# Resize image for use as an image brush

Tags: wpf, xaml, imagebrush

I want to

- load an image from a resource
- Set the image width, ensuring that it scales it's height proportionally.
- Use it as a background brush

It can't figure out the "setting its width" part.

The compromise I'm currently using is to scale it to half size. This isn't what I ideally want to do, I want to set the width to an absolute value, regardless of what the original image size was.

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="floorPlan"
        UriSource="/NavigationPathEditor;component/Images/CairnsFloorPlansCropped.png"/>

<TransformedBitmap x:Key="resizedFloorPlan" Source="{StaticResource floorPlan}">
    <TransformedBitmap.Transform>
        <ScaleTransform 
                CenterX="0"   CenterY="0" 
                ScaleX="0.5"  ScaleY="0.5" />
    </TransformedBitmap.Transform>
</TransformedBitmap>

<ImageBrush 
      x:Key="floorPlanBrush" 
      TileMode="None" Stretch="None" 
      AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top"
      ImageSource="{StaticResource resizedFloorPlan}" />
```

(Incidentally, the above code works at runtime, but throws an error in the designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that would probably be setting the [`DecodePixelWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth.aspx)/[`Height`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight.aspx) on the image itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While you were writing your answer, I changed the question a little because I figured out how to use the TransformedBitmap element. I've made the problem more specific now: I want to set the image to an absolute width rather than a proportional width.